# Proteger mi login contra inyección SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, login

saludos de ante mano, he estado programando una plataforma digital, pero comprobando su seguridad me di cuenta que un fallo, es vulnerable a una inyección SQl, con tan solo poner 'or '1'='1 en el nombre de usuario y la contraseña 'or '1'='1 podía acceder sin ningún problema, trate de solucionar el fallo, pero no he logrado corregirlo hasta el momento. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Lo siguiente es parte del código del login.

```
    <?php 

    if(!empty($_POST['usu']) and !empty($_POST['con'])){ 
        $usu=limpiar($_POST['usu']);
        $con=limpiar($_POST['con']);

        $pa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profesor WHERE doc='$usu' and con='$con'");              
        if($row=mysql_fetch_array($pa)){
            if($row['estado']=='s'){
                $nombre=$row['nom'];
                $nombre=explode(" ", $nombre);
                $nombre=$nombre[0];
                $_SESSION['user_name']=$nombre;
                $_SESSION['tipo_user']=$row['tipo'];
                $_SESSION['cod_user']=$row['doc'];
                echo mensajes('Bienvenido<br>'.$row['nom'].' '.$row['ape'].'<br> Accediendo, por favor espere...','verde').'<br>';
                echo '<center><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif"></center><br>';
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=Principal.php">';
            }else{
                echo mensajes('Usted no se encuentra Activo en la base de datos<br>Consulte con su Administrador de Sistema','rojo');   
            }
        }else{
            echo mensajes('Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecto<br>','rojo');
            echo '<center><a href="index.php" class="btn"><strong>Intentar de Nuevo</strong></a></center>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '  <input type="text" name="usu" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Usuario" autocomplete="off style="text-align:center;" required>
                <input type="password" name="con" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Contraseña" autocomplete="off" required>
                <div align="right"><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit"><strong>Ingresar</strong></button></div>';       
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: usa la funcion http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Usa sentencias preparadas. Aquí te dejo una referencia detallado como evitar la inyección SQL http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php

Comment: @ArieCwHat Sólo para información: `mysql_real_escape_string()` ha sido declarada **obsoleta** desde PHP 5.5, aparte de que **dicha función no era específicamente para prevenir la inyección SQL**, de hecho aquí (http://www.sqlinjection.net/advanced/php/mysql-real-escape-string/) se muestra un ejemplo de como a pesar de usarla se puede ser víctima de este tipo de ataques. No conviene pues recomendar el uso de mysql-real-escape-string. Saludos.

Comment: Oh lo siento, la ultima vez que yo mismo programé una conexión en PHP fue hace mucho. Suelo usar marcos de trabajo como Laravel o Codeigniter, que tienen listas las construcciones (Como Eloquent ORM) para hacer este tipo de cosas.

Answer (score 3):

Te aconsejo que uses [sentencias preparadas](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php).

La idea de una sentencia preparada nativa es inteligente y simple: la consulta y los datos se envían al servidor separados entre sí, y por lo tanto no hay posibilidad de que interfieran. Lo que hace imposible la inyección.

El principal y más esencial beneficio de las declaraciones preparadas es la eliminación de todos los peligros del formato manual.

> **Advertencia:** la extensión `mysql` fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0` y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0`. En su lugar debería utilizarse las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO_MySQL`.

Ejemplo sentencia preparada `MySQLi`:

**conexion.php**

```
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");

/* verificar conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("La conexión fallo: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

**Tu login:**

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    //Reseteamos variables.
    $usu = $con = NULL;

    if (!empty($_POST['usu']) && !empty($_POST['con'])) { 

        //Añadimos la conexion.
        require_once'conexion.php';

        //Obtenemos datos formulario
        $usu = $_POST['usu'] ? : '';
        $con = $_POST['con'] ? : '';

        //Sentencia preparada.
        $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nom, ape, tipo, doc, estado FROM profesor WHERE doc=? AND con=? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $usu, $con); //Ligamos parametros marcadores (??)
        $stmt->execute();//Ejecutamos sentencia.

        //Comprobamos si existe dicho registro.
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows === 1) {

            //Ligamos resultado desde la Base de datos.
            $stmt->bind_result($nombre, $apellido, $tipo, $doc, $estado);

            if ($stmt->fetch()) {

                if ($estado=='s') {

                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $nombre;
                    $_SESSION['tipo_user'] = $tipo;
                    $_SESSION['cod_user'] = $doc;
                    echo 'Bienvenido<br>' . $nombre . ' ' . $apellido . '<br> Accediendo, por favor espere...', 'verde') . '<br>';
                    echo '<center><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif"></center><br>';
                    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=Principal.php">';

                } else {
                    echo 'Usted no se encuentra Activo en la base de datos.<br />Consulte con su Administrador de Sistema';
                }
            } $stmt->close(); //Cerramos sentencia

        } else {
            $stmt->close(); //Cerramos sentencia
            echo "Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecto<br>";
        }        

    }else{
        echo '  <input type="text" name="usu" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Usuario" autocomplete="off style="text-align:center;" required>
                <input type="password" name="con" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Contraseña" autocomplete="off" required>
                <div align="right"><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit"><strong>Ingresar</strong></button></div>';       
    } 

?>
```